# Animation text upon click

Tags: jquery, css

```
    jQuery ( function ( $ ) {
        console.log(">>Testing animation");
        $('a.loveit').on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var text = $(this).find('div.love-text');
                text.html("<strong>Liked!</strong>");

        });

    });

**HTML**
<div>
    <a class="loveit" href="#">

    <div class="love-text">
    <i class="icn-heart"></i><strong>Like</strong>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-2">
        <span class="count">0</span>

   </div>
    </a>
```

**CSS**

```
 div.love-text {
      strong{
       -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s;
       -webkit-transition: fade-in 1s;
        -o-transition: fade-in 1s;
        -moz-transition: fade-in 1s;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in{
    from{
        // opacity:1;
        font-size: 14px;

    }
    to{
        // opacity:0;
        font-size: 23px;

    }
    }
```

When I click on the "Like", it would swap to "Liked!" without heart. The problem is that when the page loads, it already starts animation which it is not supposed to do. So when click on "like" first time, it should start animation when swapping to "LIKED!". Also, I couldn't figure how to swap back to original Like with heart if the same user clicks again.

As for animation, I am not sure about css3 - how to have easeoutback which would show text flashing with 'ripple' look (I can't explain it well). I have been looking online forever and couldn't find the animation.

Will appreciate the pointers or tips or help!

Comment: Try using this plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ 
It's really good and uses CSS3 transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JQuery Transit plugin (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)
Then you can animate easily like:

```
$('a.loveit').on('click',function(event){
    $('.love-text').transition({opacity: 0, scale: 0}, 200, 'easeOutBack', function() {

      // Animation completed
      // Change your element text..

      var text = $("#container").find('div.love-text');
      text.html("<strong>Liked!</strong>");

      $('.love-text').transition({opacity: 1, scale:1}, 500, 'easeOutBack');

    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the plugin and i have one question. how can I have text "Liked with heart" swap back if click on "Liked!" again?